# automatically updating a SP Foundation list

Tags: excel, compare, workflow-foundation, lookup

I'm REALLY hoping someone can help me here... I'm developing a database for my employer using SharePoint Foundation. The database contains 26 columns and around 100,000 rows (a Business Contacts database). We use the contents of the list to export into MS Excel to be loaded into an eMail Manager programme for carrying out email-shots. The problem I have is - the eMail Manager programme will record where recipients of the email-shot have unsubscribed, but this could be literally thousands at a time. I need to be able to "automatically" update the SharePoint list with the "Unsubscribed" data returned by the email manager (in MS Excel). I ancticipate creating a Workflow to lookup/replace defined fields. 
Can anyone help **please???**